# Writing to a csv file in a particular format

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a huge `csv` file which contains timestamps and seven other columns.

The timestamp is organized in 10 seconds interval. I've calculated the `average`, `min` and `max` of these values on hourly basis.

I need to put the output in another `csv` file organized in the following manner:

```
timestamp, Name_of_header, min, max, average
2012-05-04 06:00:00, "data1", 25.0, 56.0 40.5
2012-05-04 06:00:00, "data2", 30.0, 50.0, 40.0
..
..
..
2012-05-04 08:00:00, "data1", 10.0, 20.0, 15.0
2012-05-04 08:00:00, "data2", 15.0, 30.0 22.5
..
..
```

My working code which gives `average`, `min` and `max` on hourly basis is as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

def same_day(date_string): # remove year
    return datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime('%H:%M')
df = pd.read_csv('convertcsv.csv', parse_dates = True, index_col=0,
     usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], names = ['date', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5', 'data6', 'data7'])
hourly_avg = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('H'))
print((hourly_avg['data1]).agg([np.mean, np.min, np.max]))
(hourly_avg.mean()).to_csv('file.csv')
```

I'm stuck at getting all the values in the format that I need. How can I put all the `data1`, `data2`, `data3`.. under one header and then print their `average`, `min` and `max` values on one row at a time?

Comment: Would you like us to write it for you? (c:

Comment: no, but i'm quite new to Python, so any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: Try some code to do what you expect to do. If it does not work as expected, post it here, with the error message. Then we will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you would have quite a few columns to aggregate - assume 'date' is your timestamp, there seem to be seven, ie, data1 - data7. If you apply three aggregation functions to these seven columns (mean, min, max) you'll get 7 x 3 columns with a hierarchical `MultiIndex` (where `.agg(dict)` works differently as for 'ordinary' columns). Example follows, including saving to csv at the end. [`GroupBy` docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once) and [`to_csv` docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1000, 7)), columns=['data_' + str(i) for i in range(7)], index=pd.date_range(date(2015,11,29), periods=1000, freq='15S'))

                       data_0    data_1    data_2    data_3    data_4  \
2015-11-29 00:00:00  0.331546  0.317863  0.616388  0.784063  0.968004   
2015-11-29 00:00:15  0.299468  0.971885  0.954483  0.856748  0.230223   
2015-11-29 00:00:30  0.246160  0.618193  0.902762  0.518121  0.705881   
2015-11-29 00:00:45  0.875753  0.629994  0.029394  0.883197  0.939194   
2015-11-29 00:01:00  0.696372  0.536321  0.632785  0.009850  0.951280   

                       data_5    data_6  
2015-11-29 00:00:00  0.829210  0.323449  
2015-11-29 00:00:15  0.753155  0.619336  
2015-11-29 00:00:30  0.149181  0.679280  
2015-11-29 00:00:45  0.236912  0.024689  
2015-11-29 00:01:00  0.171320  0.520080
```

Grouping by hour, calculating group-wise stats:

```
hourly_stats = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('H')).agg([np.sum, np.min, np.max])

                       data_0                        data_1            \
                         mean      amin      amax      mean      amin   
2015-11-29 00:00:00  0.493442  0.003107  0.999432  0.495162  0.003796   
2015-11-29 01:00:00  0.506108  0.001073  0.988778  0.485588  0.001207   
2015-11-29 02:00:00  0.484978  0.003669  0.993387  0.495174  0.006063   
2015-11-29 03:00:00  0.510354  0.011436  0.997326  0.489296  0.000456   
2015-11-29 04:00:00  0.544405  0.040678  0.965896  0.542452  0.049254   

                                 data_2                        data_3  \
                         amax      mean      amin      amax      mean   
2015-11-29 00:00:00  0.994239  0.487602  0.001981  0.994280  0.491253   
2015-11-29 01:00:00  0.998454  0.467457  0.001216  0.997955  0.511204   
2015-11-29 02:00:00  0.999235  0.513108  0.003046  0.998595  0.524719   
2015-11-29 03:00:00  0.996543  0.528340  0.002706  0.995325  0.488485   
2015-11-29 04:00:00  0.984905  0.506434  0.025606  0.925806  0.535858   

                       ...                 data_4                      \
                       ...         amax      mean      amin      amax   
2015-11-29 00:00:00    ...     0.991856  0.487274  0.010722  0.998514   
2015-11-29 01:00:00    ...     0.999489  0.533160  0.003481  0.982976   
2015-11-29 02:00:00    ...     0.998216  0.482723  0.001257  0.999445   
2015-11-29 03:00:00    ...     0.999063  0.495377  0.002491  0.997803   
2015-11-29 04:00:00    ...     0.948984  0.522290  0.011772  0.998149   

                       data_5                        data_6            \
                         mean      amin      amax      mean      amin   
2015-11-29 00:00:00  0.523222  0.005653  0.999984  0.488832  0.004678   
2015-11-29 01:00:00  0.490922  0.000483  0.998804  0.500331  0.001843   
2015-11-29 02:00:00  0.478979  0.011122  0.998308  0.517226  0.001161   
2015-11-29 03:00:00  0.527019  0.008794  0.999160  0.461164  0.002979   
2015-11-29 04:00:00  0.415962  0.004843  0.975577  0.523150  0.050968   


                         amax  
2015-11-29 00:00:00  0.993302  
2015-11-29 01:00:00  0.998207  
2015-11-29 02:00:00  0.997752  
2015-11-29 03:00:00  0.999652  
2015-11-29 04:00:00  0.998608
```

You can save the result straight to csv (option: rename columns with `hourly_stats.columns = ['col_name_1', 'col_name_2', .... 'col_name_21']`:

```
hourly_stats.to_csv('path/to/file.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) it prints the output in the way you've shown. AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'to_csv' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method                    But I still get this error while printing to csv file

Comment: That would happen if you were trying to call to_csv on df.groupby() before calling .agg(). The later returns a DataFrame, the former a DataFrameGroupBy object, hence the error. So df.groupby().agg().to_csv() should work, but df.groupby().agg() should give the error you're seeing.

Comment: Exactly, I did that and it worked fine :) thank you for al your help. Out of curiosity, my data is organized in interval of 10 seconds, if there is some data where interval is more than 10 seconds, how do I check the gaps and print it? i'm trying to do                                                                       df['num_gaps'] =  df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('H'))
df.groupby(df.index.time)['num_gaps'].sum()                                            but i'm not sure if is corect

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have posted it as a new question. If you can help in any way, it would really be great. Thanks.